# how to pass id in form dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I make a view from my json object .I am facing two issues 
1) how can I send id dynamically which is generated dynamically form  .in my case I take a constant ID. ng-form="myfrm" which out any id .i need to get  id from json  which is this "studentName": "abc", id should be "abc" id="abc"

2) i need to add select  or drop down type in SWITCH . select mean drop down.i need to add drop drown when type is SWITCH and option give in input values

http://plnkr.co/edit/EM3tqekUxaiUZA1b7Fk4?p=preview

```
angular.forEach($scope.formInputs, function(value, key) {
  /* do something for all key: value pairs */
  $scope.inputs.push({
    "type":value.inputType.toLowerCase(),
    "name":value.name,
    "required": value.required
  });
});
```

how to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: I am sure if this is from my connection or something else. I can't access your plnkr. I keep getting the "Unable to connect to any application instances." as a response. Can you verify that?

Comment: please http://plnkr.co/edit/saTmeU2Wv9Zn1j3YEZ2l?p=preview